# How to extract JSON data from the HTML data using Python?

Tags: python, html, json, regex

I'm trying to make a python script that can read JSON data in outlook Email.But problem is how to extract JSON data from HTML data. This is my Original JSON data that I want to extract.

```
{
"vpn_detail":
    {
        "username":"harnishs",  
        "tokens":   
            [
                "85188605",
                "00422786",
            ],
        "cluster_name":"*******.com"
    }

}
```

So I have read my this JSON data using imaplib in outlook but it's read JSON data in HTML.So this JSON data is converted into HTML, Its read outlook email like this(In HTML Form),

```
b'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=\r\n1">\r\n<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margi=\r\nn-bottom:0;} --></style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=3D"ltr">\r\n<div id=3D"divtagdefaultwrapper" style=3D"font-size:12pt;color:#000000;font=\r\n-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif;" dir=3D"ltr">\r\n<p style=3D"margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0"></p>\r\n<div>{<br>\r\n&quot;vpn_detail&quot;:<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;{<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&quot;username&quot;:&quot;kushpate&q=\r\nuot;,&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&quot;tokens&quot;:&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;[<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;85188605&quot;,<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;00422786&quot;,<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;94548619&quot;,<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;51249494&quot;,<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;HHEF0EA5&quot;,<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;2E09A81E&quot;<br>\r\n&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;],<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&quot;cluster_name&quot;:&quot;bgl13-=\r\nvpn-cluster-2.cisco.com&quot;<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;}<br>\r\n<br>\r\n}</div>\r\n<br>\r\n<p></p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

So Now from this HTML data, I want same JSON file,
I have make my code like this,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
MyStr =""" HTML data """
soup = BeautifulSoup(MyStr, "html.parser")
print(soup.text.strip().replace(" ", ""))
```

So this code give me this result,

```
b'


<!--P{margin-top:0;margi=
n-bottom:0;}-->




{
"vpn_detail":
   {
      "username":"harnishs&q;=
uot;,   
      "tokens":   =
;
         [
            =
;"85188605",
            =
;"00422786",
            =
;"94548619",
            =
;
          ],
      "cluster_name":"***********.com"
   }

}





'
```

But I want this data same as input JSON data, still its did not  exact mining. Suggest me any changes so I can get same JSON data through email.

Comment: Your chances will vastly improve if you send the JSON data as a plain text email instead of an HTML email.

Comment: And you need to specify an encoding to get rid of all the `&q;=` tags...

Comment: Try `re.search(r'{\s*"\w+".*}', soup.text.strip().decode("utf8"), re.S).group()`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew YES, My output is improve but still not get exact JSON data. I want to remove this line (&q;=
uot;, ) from username . Now My Output is like this,
```
{
"vpn_detail":
    {
        "username":"harnishs&q;=
uot;,    
        "tokens":    =
;
            [
                =
;"85188605",
                =
;"00422786",
                =
;"94548619",
                =
;"51249494",
                =
;"HHEF0EA5",
                =
;"2E09A81E"
              ],
        "cluster_name":"bgl13-=
vpn-cluster-2.cisco.com"
    }

}

```

Comment: `re.search(r'{\s*"\w+".*}', s.decode("UTF8"), re.S).group().strip().replace('&q;=\nuot;', '"')`? Is the newline always there, after `=`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There is no = sign , I want the data same as JSON data that above I have mentioned. This is my JSON data, I want data same like this.
```
{
"vpn_detail":
 {
  "username":"harnishs", 
  "tokens": 
   [
    "85188605",
    "00422786",
    "94548619",
    "51249494",
    "HHEF0EA5",
    "2E09A81E"
     ],
  "cluster_name":"bgl13-vpn-cluster-2.cisco.com"
 }

}
```

Comment: I have remove s.decode("UTF8") line because its give me [AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'] so it was run but now in your 2nd comment its give me this error [TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
] @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You need to convert the bytes string to a UTF8 string to work with strings.  I see you have `b'...'` in the question, hence my `.decode("utf8")`.

Comment: Sorry, `re.sub(r'\s+(?:=\s*;\s*)?', ' ', re.search(r'{\s*"\w+".*}', s.decode("UTF8"), re.S).group().strip()).replace('&q;= uot;','"')`, see https://ideone.com/ULtkk8

Comment: but  [  b'...'  ] is already removed due to your first comment. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: See https://ideone.com/ULtkk8, does it work as expected?

Comment: NameError: name 's' is not defined @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @HarnishShah  I use `s` in my demo, use **your varaible**, `soup.text`. `re.sub(r'\s+(?:=\s*;\s*)?', ' ', re.search(r'{\s*"\w+".*}', soup.text.decode("UTF8"), re.S).group().strip()).replace('&q;= uot;','"')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now my code is like this 
soup = BeautifulSoup(MyStr, "html.parser")
soup5 = soup.MyStr.re.sub(r'\s+(?:=\s*;\s*)?', ' ', re.search(r'{\s*"\w+".*}', soup.MyStr.decode("UTF8"), re.S).group().strip()).replace('&q;= uot;','"')
print(soup5)

now got this error [ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 're' ]

Comment: You are not using my code. String has no `re` property of course. **Try this code: https://ideone.com/YwmJH3**. It does not compile online, it should work in your console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195507/discussion-between-harnish-shah-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may greatly simplify your task with `html2text` library that will do almost all the job, you will only need to remove the unnecessary punctuation and replace the garbled quotation marks with real `"`:

```
import re, json, html2text

MyStr = b'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=\r\n1">\r\n<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margi=\r\nn-bottom:0;} --></style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=3D"ltr">\r\n<div id=3D"divtagdefaultwrapper" dir=3D"ltr" style=3D"font-size: 12pt; colo=\r\nr: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif, &quot;EmojiFo=\r\nnt&quot;, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, NotoCo=\r\nlorEmoji, &quot;Segoe UI Symbol&quot;, &quot;Android Emoji&quot;, EmojiSymb=\r\nols;">\r\n<p style=3D"margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0"></p>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>{<br>\r\n&quot;vpn_detail&quot;:<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;{<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&quot;username&quot;:&quot;kushpate&q=\r\nuot;,&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&quot;tokens&quot;:&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;[<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;85188605&quot;,<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;00422786&quot;,<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;94548619&quot;,<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;51249494&quot;,<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;HHEF0EA5&quot;,<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp=\r\n;&quot;2E09A81E&quot;<br>\r\n&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;],<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&quot;cluster_name&quot;:&quot;bgl13-=\r\nvpn-cluster-2.cisco.com&quot;<br>\r\n&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;}<br>\r\n<br>\r\n}</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<br>\r\n<p></p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
MyStrTxt = html2text.html2text(MyStr.decode("utf8"))
clean_string = re.sub(r'(&q;=\s*uot;)|=\s*;\s*', lambda x: '"' if x.group(1) else '', MyStrTxt)
js = json.loads(clean_string)
print(js['vpn_detail']['username']) 
# => 'kushpate'
```

NOTES:

- Your input string is a byte string, you need to convert it to a Unicode UTF8 string, hence,  `MyStr.decode("utf8")` is necessary
- `html2text.html2text(MyStr.decode("utf8"))` will clean the HTML from your string, you will get your JSON right away
- `re.sub(r'(&q;=\s*uot;)|=\s*;\s*', lambda x: '"' if x.group(1) else '', MyStrTxt)` removes all occurrences of `=;` with spaces in between if any or will replace `&q;=`+zero or more whitespaces+`uot;` with a real `"` char.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @WiktorStribizew but I don't want to remove manually because every time when I am reading email using python this JSON data will different but format is same so How can I get back same JSON data from HTML data, that's my question. Your code gives me answer only [kushpate ] while I want whole JSON data.

Comment: @HarnishShah `print(js)`. Please play around with the code. It is really easy to `print()` any variable you are interested in.

Comment: yes It's working. Thanks @Wiktor for the best solution.